# Windows task scheduler website opener

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

Yes I know this has been handled in various threads dating back to 2012 and such, but hear me out please.

I've seen multiple methodologies for opening a web page in task scheduler varying from
using a .bat file to run start https://www.insertwebsitenamehere.com

starting iexplore.exe with arguments url here both via cmd.exe and via calling the executable directly
starting chrome.exe with arguments of URL here both via cmd.exe and via calling the executable directly

Tested the .bat file it works

task scheduler shows that task started successful with op code 1
action started with op code 1
action completed with op code 2
task completed with op code 2

no errors in the logs, however it just does not pop up.

Does anyone know if Microsoft has restricted the functionality of task scheduler for security purposes or am I just missing something here?

Comment: It depends on how you setup your task. You cannot run it with highest privileges because then it is launched outside the user's scope with no interactive elements. Same applies to run it whether the user is logged in or not. But it is possible iexplorer.exe forwards it to edge and it fails because of that.

Comment: No change in behaviour after removing highest privileges.